# I have removed Call and SMS permission from manifest still im getting error while uploading apk

Tags: android

My App was removed by google because of presence of SMS and Call Permission in manifest. Now I have removed both the permission then also I'm not able to upload the apk .play store asking for the Permissions Declaration Form

[image]

Comment: @Cristan im getting this error now...                                                                 
Based on our review, we found your app’s expressed user experience did not match your declared core functionality Default SMS handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler). Please remove these permissions from your app.
Default handler capability was listed on your declaration form, but your app does not appear to have default handler capability. Please submit a revised declaration form.

Comment: Check [steps](https://gist.github.com/manishpatelgt/224a330a5d4c7eaf783ca3ff5d522274)

Comment: Thank you all for suggestions . My problem resolved after removing PHONE_STATE permission from manifest file.

Comment: Glad to hear that

Answer (score 2):

Most likely some library you're using is adding the permissions. You can remove them during merge by adding the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS” tools:node=”remove” />
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.SEND_SMS” tools:node=”remove” />
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.WRITE_SMS” tools:node=”remove” />
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.READ_SMS” tools:node=”remove” />
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774787/why-does-removing-permission-from-androidmanifest-xml-not-work) for additional information.

Answer (score 1):

You have to release a build with those permissions and fill the form (form will appear automatically on release page), then after that, you have to upload a build without those permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem recently and i have to removed those permissions and later my app got published. Please type all your permission you using in your app?

Answer (score 0):

Remove SMS and CALL-Log permission from manifest file and Build new APK upload in Internal Test Track and **deactivate previously released APK in internal Test track** and roll out, Then release same APK in Alpha and Beta, Then **Previously Declared Permissions** will be **automatically removed and release app to production and roll out**